# Mysql to Cassandra java null pointer exception

Tags: mysql, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

My code is

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import com.datastax.driver.core.BatchStatement;

import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Row;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;

import com.datastax.driver.core.PreparedStatement;

public class DataPortCluster {

    private static Cluster cluster; 
    private static Session session;
    public static Cluster connect(String node) {

        return Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(node).build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{ 

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement  stm = null;


        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ksfedata";
            String uName = "root";
            String uPass= "root";
            conn= DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);

            stm = conn.createStatement();

            String sql = "SELECT c.id, c.branch, c.firstName, c.lastName, c.dob, c.uniqueId, c.mobilePhone, c.isKSFEEmployee "
                    + ",CONCAT_WS('',offaddress.line1,offaddress.line2, offaddress.pinCode) AS Official,"
                    + "CONCAT_WS('',peraddress.line1,peraddress.line2, peraddress.pinCode) AS Permanent,"
                    + "CONCAT_WS('',resaddress.line1,resaddress.line2, resaddress.pinCode) AS Residential,"
                    + "CONCAT_WS('',tempaddress.line1,tempaddress.line2, tempaddress.pinCode) AS Temporary,"
                    + "CONCAT_WS('',commaddress.line1,commaddress.line2, commaddress.pinCode) AS Communication"
                    + " FROM customerdup c  "
                    + "LEFT JOIN customeraddressdup as offaddress ON (offaddress.customerId =c.id AND  offaddress.customerBranch = c.branch  AND offaddress.addresstype=0) "
                    + "LEFT JOIN customeraddressdup as peraddress ON (peraddress.customerId =c.id AND  peraddress.customerBranch = c.branch  AND peraddress.addresstype=1) "
                    + "LEFT JOIN customeraddressdup as resaddress ON (resaddress.customerId =c.id AND  resaddress.customerBranch = c.branch  AND resaddress.addresstype=2) "
                    + "LEFT JOIN customeraddressdup as tempaddress ON (tempaddress.customerId =c.id AND  tempaddress.customerBranch = c.branch  AND tempaddress.addresstype=3) "
                    + "LEFT JOIN customeraddressdup as commaddress ON (commaddress.customerId =c.id AND  commaddress.customerBranch = c.branch  AND commaddress.addresstype=4)";



            //          String sql = "Select ID,FIRSTNAME,DOB,MOBILEPHONE,EMAIL From customerdup LIMIT 3";
            ResultSet rst;
            rst = stm.executeQuery(sql);


            String serverIp = "localhost";
            String keyspace = "events";

            cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(serverIp).build();
            session = cluster.connect(keyspace);


            PreparedStatement statement = session.prepare("insert into customer (branch, uniqueid, communication,customerid,dob,firstname,isksfeemp,lastname,mobile,official,permanent,residential,temporary) "
                    + "values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ;");
            //BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(statement);
            BatchStatement batchStatement = new BatchStatement();
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            while (rst.next()) { 

                int id = rst.getInt("id");
                String branch = rst.getString("branch");
                String firstname = rst.getString("firstname");
                String lastname = rst.getString("lastname");
                Date datecheck = rst.getDate("dob");
                LocalDate dob = LocalDate.fromMillisSinceEpoch(datecheck.getTime());
                String uniqueId =  rst.getString("uniqueId");
                String mobile = rst.getString("mobilePhone");
                int isKSFEEmployee = rst.getInt("isKSFEEmployee");
                String Official = rst.getString("Official");
                String Permanent = rst.getString("Permanent");
                String Residential = rst.getString("Residential");
                String Temporary = rst.getString("Temporary");
                String Communication = rst.getString("Communication");


                batchStatement.add(statement.bind(branch,uniqueId,Communication,id,dob,firstname,isKSFEEmployee,lastname,mobile,Official,Permanent,Residential,Temporary));
                //session.execute(boundStatement.bind(id,name,Dob,mobNo,email));

            }

            session.execute(batchStatement);
            long endTime   = System.nanoTime();
            long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
            System.out.println(totalTime + "++++++++++++++555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555");

            String cqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM customer";
            for (Row row : session.execute(cqlStatement)) {
                System.out.println(row.toString());
            } 


        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        finally {

            if (conn != null && stm != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                    stm.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                conn = null;
            }
            session.close();
            cluster.close();
        }



    }
}
```

When i tried debug my code i got an error with

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DataPortCluster.main(DataPortCluster.java:121)
```

at the line

```
cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(serverIp).build();
```

Do not know what is the problem is. If any one can help it will be much appreciable. In my view the problem is occurring during the connection for cassandra. Why does the error thrown at the above line. the serverip i given is localhost.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(serverIp)` is probably `null`. Are you sure that no port is needed? Or did you try `127.0.0.1` ? *"Contact points are addresses of Cassandra nodes that the driver uses to discover the cluster topology."*

Comment: by the way, line 121 is `session.close();` - at least in the code here

Comment: i treied with 127.0.0.1 but still showing the same error. yes Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(serverIp) is null. but i don't know what the problem is

Comment: `Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(serverIp) ` can never be `null`. See the [source code](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.x/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster.java). Did you read my second comment regarding the line 121? it doesn't match the code here